# how to get input data in the same page using php

Tags: php, html

how can i get the content of the input tag in php , as i search i have to put the input tags into form tag and then pass them to another page , is it possible to get the content in that page and do something like send them via email and then clear the input tags content ?!!
these are the thing i found to pass the content :

```
<form action="recevie.php" method="post" >
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="fname" />
  Age:
  <input type="text" name="age" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You mean, you need to get the form data in the same page without page refresh?

Comment: If you mean submit the form to the same page, you just need to remove that `action` form attribute. Do you mean so?

Comment: Put your entire code inside one file, preferably PHP on top of HTML, then use `action=""` including an `isset` conditional statement; or use Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the page into the same page that's you are in, but is not the best practice.

You Should Redirect the page Back to your form's page after you process the form, you can utilize header("Location: example.php"); to page back or to redirect where you want to.

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access to your form data without manually submitting it, you'll have to use Javascript.

In Javascript then, you can send an Ajax request with this data if you need processing them on the PHP side.